# Wildfly - Required services that are not installed - TransactionSynchronizationRegistry

Tags: java, transactions, wildfly, jta, jts

I'm try to enable `JTS` but my deployment fail with this message:

```
2018-04-26 19:57:48,429 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "my-app.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 

{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.txn.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry",
        "jboss.txn.TransactionManager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"my-app.war\".REGISTER is missing [jboss.txn.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry,  jboss.txn.TransactionManager]"] 
}
```

How can I install/enable those services?

I am using Wildfly 12.

Thanks!